# iTunes Connect auto-renewable subscription configuration

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm configuring an auto-renewable subscription for an app on iTunes connect, and on the duration configuration panel there are two mandatory "Duration" fields: a select box with the possible options, and a free text one, for which I can't find any information about.
What is the purpose of that second free text duration field?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently seems to be a bug on iTunes Connect. The free text duration field will be converted into the product id.